# Flask second parameter returns null

Tags: bash, curl

when I try to return the second argument `background` for my Flask application, I get a null value, but it works fine for `original`

```
> curl http://127.0.0.1:5000?original="sdsd" & background="/szzzzzz" 

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def API():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        original = request.args.get('original')
        background = request.args.get('background')
        result =  background
        return jsonify(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely your shell is ignoring the part after the `&` because that character is signaling the shell the run the first part of the command in the background.

Try running your curl command like this:

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:5000?original=sdsd&background=/szzzzzz"
```

The quotation marks will escape the `&` character so that the entire string is passed to curl.

Comment: it worked ! but aren't we supposed to put the original & background arguments in double-quotes since they are strings ?

Comment: When you pass an HTTP parameter, it is always treated as a string. In fact, the only way to treat a parameter as a number (for example, `?age=42`) is to have your Python code cast the value from string `"42"` to an integer.